# Clean Code Pattern for class function requiring many inputs

Tags: python, design-patterns, coding-style, bigdata, dask

I have a fxn that loops through a huge set of data (using dask). The structure of the fxn is something like

```
def fxn(input 1, input 2, ... input 20):
    component_1 = otherclass.fxn_a(input 1, input 2, input 3, input 4)
    component_2 = otherclass.fxn_b(input 5, input 6, input 7, input 8, input 9, input 10)
    component_3 = otherclass.fxn_c(input 11, input 12, input 13, input 14, input 15)
    output_1 = outputclass.fxn_1(component_1, component_2, input 16, input 17, input 18)
    output_2 = outputclass.fxn_2(component_3, input 19, input 20)
    return output_1 + output_2
```

I was trying to think through how I should break this up. Should each component be made into its own small class with only the necessary inputs for it?

```
def fxn(input 16, input 17, input 18, input 19, input 20):
    output_1 = outputclass.fxn_1(component1class.get_component(), component2class.get_component(), input 16, input 17, input 18)
    output_2 = outputclass.fxn_2(component3class.get_component(), input 19, input 20)
    return output_1 + output_2
```

And then even further:

```
def fxn():
    output = outputclass.get_sum_components()
    return output
```

Would that be the best approach or should I do something else?

Comment: This will likely get marked as "Opinion-based", since you don't have a clear problem you want to solve.

Comment: Gotcha, that's ok. I'm curious what approaches those with experience use in these situations

Comment: Please try to provide a [mcve](/help/mcve).